# Chrome, firefox, or opera preload changes

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, browser, opera

Is there any way to "edit" a "server side" javascript file in one of the mentioned browsers that will save the js edits on the client side and replace the server side scripts?

Basically I want to edit the javascripts on the server. Obviously I can't save them on the server so they need to be saved on the client side(my computer) and the browser needs to load my scripts instead.

It shouldn't be hard to do at all but I've not been able to find any way to accomplish this.

---

Edit:

I want to modify the javascript's from a site I do not own or have write access too. e.g.,

Html page uses some javascript page on server. I want to modify this javascript file(the actual file).

I can download and save the javascript file BUT the html page will always use the one on the server because that is what is in the script tag. I need to modify the script tag of the html page to point to the local javascript file BEFORE the html page's scripts are executed(else the javascript from the server will be used).

here, for example, is a script tag from SE:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It uses a non-local javascript file. I need to replace this line with my own line before any javascript is executed. It would like like:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="file://C:/temp/myjquery.min.js"></script>
```

or whatever. (this way, I can modify the jquery file and have it execute my own version of the one on the server)

I, could, ofcourse, download the html file and modify it BUT then php code may not work among other things. (for example, relative links will be broke)

Comment: Use Opera. It is easy. Right click > Source > Make changes > Apply Changes. The script source is now modified.

Answer (score 1):

this is usually very easy in Opera: Just view source, edit what you want and use the special "Tools > Advanced > Reload from cache" command **instead of** a normal reload. Voila, you'll be running the site with your modified scripts..

(There are some exceptions, related to specific no-caching techniques some sites use it won't work 100% for all files - but it certainly should work for anything served from googleapis.com)

Answer (score 0):

No problem, you want to use bookmark-lets for this. Indeed it is easy, just remember to use an anonymous autoexecuting function: `javascript:(function(){ //commands })();`
In the *sane good old day's* one could even place this javascript directly into your addresses, but nowaday's some browser-builders (like firefox we coders USED to trust in the old day's) are being a 'good boy' and listen to facebook's 'demands' to kill normal standard functionality in favor of their lack on comprehending closures... But alas.. 
Ofcourse you could also create a bookmark to fix firefox's insanity, again reclaiming power to the user :)

Every time you visit the site, you click your bookmarklet. Done.
One can even make it 'memory resistant' for as long als you are on the same page (if you really want to). Naturally power is with the user/visitor *AS IT SHOULD BE*, not with the webmaster (who already publicly shared whatever info).

You might also look into greasemonky on firefox and comparable solutions.

Good luck

Comment: No, I need to modify the javascript files. I guess I need to make it more clear. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/)

It allows you to edit css files and have the browser apply the changes without refreshing the browser.

The windows version is in alpha right now but the Mac version works quite well for CSS.

I don't know if it does Javascript but I think it might.

You could also try the [Chrome DevTools](https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave/). It's a chrome extension that does just what you want with javascript and css.

Comment: No, These only work for local files. I'm trying to "edit" the files from a server I do not have write access too(hence I need to save the files locally and have the browser use those files in replace of the server files when I browse to that page).

Comment: If you don't have write access to the server then you shouldn't expect it to be 'easy to do'. The best you can try to do is have your browser be configured to use certain .js/.css files when you go to a specific website. Opera allows this functionality. It let you have 'user scripts' and 'user styles' that will be used on specific pages of your liking. I don't know if other browsers support this feature.

Comment: But will it let you "replace" the javascript file? If the site uses www.somesite.com/somescript.js can I have it not load that file and load mine instead? and it should be 'easy to do' since it simply is loading up a load version of the file instead of from the server... it would be a relatively trivial task for a web browser to do.

Comment: Opera won't let you do that. It only lets you load additional scripts on a specific site, not replace scripts, at least not that I know of. I agree that it 'could' be easy to do but without existing tools/features to do so it isn't exactly easy.

Comment: I found an article on the Opera dev forums. It let's you add event listeners to a 'BeforeScript' event. You can prevent the loading of the script this way and then add your own script tag to the document pointing to the script of your choosing. More detail can be found here : http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/examples/

Comment: @JerrySaravia @AbstractDissonance Opera will allow you to replace scripts. For example, go to `www.somesite.com/somescript.js` > Right click > Source > Select all > Delete everything > Apply Changes. The script is now blanked!

Comment: @XP1, cool, didn't know that. Opera has some nice developer tools.

Answer (score -2):

Build a string on the server side to write all your javascript code on the server side.